# Error on execute crosstab return n+ tuples

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

I try to get all results using these conditions to list all company have tickets with status opened, and list but I got message.

Using crosstab I want use other table in future.

> ERROR: invalid return type
>   DETAIL: Query-specified return tuple has 3 columns but crosstab returns 49150.

My query:

```
select * 
from crosstab ('select id as id_ticket,company_id, created_at, description 
                from tickets 
                where close != false 
                group by tickets.id, company_id, created_at  
                order by 1',
               'select distinct(created_at) from tickets order by 1') 
      as tickets(id int, company_id int, description text);
```

**i want get this output data**

```
ID     COMPANY_ID   DESCRIPTION    UPDATED_AT   CREATED_AT
521521   1           TEST DEBUG     .2019-01-10 23;59   .2019-01-10 23;5
```

Comment: Can you show the result you are trying to get?

Comment: How do you plan to use `created_at`? Since it is a time stamp, there are 49150 unique values, and crosstab will attempt to make one column for each. Do you mean to truncate, so you get only the date portion, and not the time portion?

Comment: i want extract  ID, company ID, all tickets from each company to ordenate with from created_at desc or asc i remove the created_at but error continue. @Jeremy

Comment: i want extract ID, company ID, all tickets from each company to ordenate with from created_at desc or asc i remove the created_at but error continue. @richyen

Comment: This question and your other question about crosstab are both very difficult to answer.  Please show your table definitions and the actual result you want, not a description of the result.  Ideally, you would also include some sample data that matches the result you want.

Comment: What do you mean by "ordenate" -- could you *show* us what you have (your data), and what you want (desired output)?

Comment: wanted to put in order of update, example ticket was updated on 01/01 of the current year at some point of the day, wanted to organize the output data by date and time of inclusion in the database. @richyen i updated post with sample output.